# What's the difference between "dissatisfied" and "unsatisfied"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, past-participles, negative-prefixes

Is there a clear-cut difference between *dissatisfied* and *unsatisfied*?

Comment: Dissatisfied refers to a particular event leaving one unsatisfied.
Unsatisfied is a state of mind where our desires haven't been quenched by sonethings or something.

Answer (score 20):

The feeling connected with a lack of satisfaction can have two different components:

- A sense of incompleteness, which leaves one feeling *unsatisfied*
- A sense of wrongness, which leaves one feeling *dissatisfied*

Naturally, both senses may overlap in certain situations. Take the following example:

> John's father was unsatisfied by the principal's explanation of his son's injuries.

[He suspected that some important details were missing from the principal's explanation.]

> John's father was dissatisfied with the principal's explanation of his son's injuries.

[He suspected that he was being lied to.]

If I was John's father in this situation, I would most likely choose to describe my feeling as *dissatisfaction*, which would better reflect my state of active displeasure, and would also encompass both the incompleteness and the wrongness I had perceived in the principal's explanation.

Had I merely felt that some information was missing, the result would have been *a lack of satisfaction.*

Answer (score 8):

The big difference between the two words is that *dissatisfied* is only used of people. That is, a person can be dissatisfied by the amount of food they receive; but their hunger would be unsatisfied. You can use *dissatisfied* in places where you could use *disappointed*. When some requirement is not met, we can say that requirement is *unsatisfied* (but we would never say it's dissatisfied).

A more subtle and semantic difference is that *unsatisfied* often implies that a greater amount of something is needed, whereas *dissatisfied* tends to imply that the quality of something was poor.